# How to access an HTML tag in ASP.NET code behind without postback

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The current way I access elements in the code behind is by making them server.

Example

```
<div id="abc" runat="server" > Test </div>
```

Then in code behind I can simply use something like abc.visible=false

However this seem to cause a postback. What is the other ways possible to access elements from the post back or to disable the post-back.

The reason I want to hide elements is some users depending their roles should not be able to see these elements.

Comment: That doesn't _cause_ a postback, but you can't access elements from serverside if you are not on the server. If you just want to hide them client-side you can use javascript/jQuery and/or CSS. However, elements which are `Visible=false`(serverside) don't exist on clientside at all.

Comment: So you say even though it flagged as runat=server if I hide it does not cause postback?

Comment: No, not more postbacks than without `runat=server`. It just says ASP.NET that it has to create a control in server-memory, so that you are able to access it there. Otherwise you can't access it on serverside.

Comment: Great. Then do you see any drawback in the way i'm doing it now? I was concerned about page postback. Do I really get something more by using Jquery or javascript? I want to avoid cluttering my presentation layer with anykind of coding(script) as much as possible

Comment: No, absolutely fine what we can see. But as mentioned, if you want to change the visibility on client-side without a postback you can't use `Visible=false`.

Comment: Very good put this as an answer for future reference so I can accept it . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't cause a postback, but you can't access elements from serverside if you are not on the server. If you just want to hide them client-side you can use javascript/jQuery and/or CSS. However, elements which are `Visible=false`(serverside) don't exist on client-side at all.

So the `runat=server` doesn't cause  more postbacks than without it. It just says ASP.NET that it has to create a control in server-memory, so that you are able to access it there.

But as mentioned, if you want to change the visibility on client-side without a postback you can't use `Visible=false`. Then use CSS either with a class or inline:

```
abc.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

or without codebehind:

```
<div id="abc" style="display:none"> Test </div>
```

Now you could access it from client-side even if it's invisible, for example to switch visibility.

Comment: Great . I assume to use abc.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none"); I still need to have runat="server". is this correct?

Comment: @SNash: yes, edited my answer to show a way without `runat=server`.

Comment: But if I remove runat="server" , code behind does not event see abc so it can not call its methods . such as abc.Attributes

Comment: @SNash: yes, but if you use `<div id="abc" style="display:none"> Test </div>` you don't need to access it on server. Have you seen [what i've edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29300626/revisions) in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use LoginView?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <RoleGroups>
            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    Content visible to Admin role
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:RoleGroup>
             <asp:RoleGroup Roles="User">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    Content visible to User role
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:RoleGroup>
        </RoleGroups>
    </asp:LoginView>
```

Or you can put your content in a server side control like `placeholder` and check If user is in role then make it visible.

in your pageyou put your place holders and role specific content into them:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AdminPlaceholder" runat="server">
        Admin Only Content
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="UserPlaceholder" runat="server">
        Admin Only Content
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

then you show and hide them in the codebehind:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            // Make Admin content visible here
            AdminPlaceholder.Visible = true;
            UserPlaceholder.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
        {
            // Make User content visible and hide Admin content
            AdminPlaceholder.Visible = false;
            UserPlaceholder.Visible = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            // Login Please
        }
```

Thus postback will be no concern because the server will decide what to show to which user..

Comment: // Make Admin content visible here ? how?

Comment: "// Make Admin content visible here" means that when you put admin only content in a serverside control (such as placeholder), say `AdminPlaceholder` for the ID of `placeholder` and you then make it visible here as: `AdminPlaceholder.Visible = True;`

Comment: very useful..+1 for this

Answer (score 0):

You could use client side JavaScript to hide the elements if you want to avoid all communication between client and server. Another option is ASP.NET Page Methods, which don't post the whole page back. They just send the required data between a Javascript function and an ASP.NET method. 
[PageMethods In ASP.NET AJAX](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2)